# How do I set enum data type in doctrine 2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

In annotation based mapping, as per the documentation of doctrine, we can do as shown below:

```
/** @Column(type="string", columnDefinition="ENUM('visible', 'invisible')") */
```

My question is how do I represent this in yaml meta data file for doctrine?

I want to do something like this:

```
fields:
status:
  type: string
  columnDefinition: ....
```

I am using symfony 2 as framework

Comment: Have you tried what you wrote?

Comment: i dont know how to convert ENUM('visible','invisible') into yaml expression, i m new to yaml

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just use:

```
fields:
status:
  type: string
  columnDefinition: ENUM('visible', 'invisible')
```

Comment: I guess this works for MySQL only, right? Because in Postgres you will have to actually `CREATE TYPE`

Answer (score 1):

```
status:
    type: enum
    values: ['visible', 'invisible']
```

https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine1/en/latest/manual/yaml-schema-files.html#enums