# ENUM in Symfony/Doctrine overrides with VARCHAR

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

A small sketch of my situation. I have an entity called "ticket" and ticket has a field called "state". The states possible are: "Open" and "Closed". I want to store these states in a MySQL enumeration.

Doctrine doesn't support ENUM out of the box, so I added:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        mapping_types
            enum: string
```

So far so good.

Now in my doctrine YAML file (Ticket.orm.yml) I added the following:

```
fields:
    state:
        type: string
        columnDefinition: ENUM('Open', 'Closed')
```

The problem I encounter is when I run

```
app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

Is that it stores the field as a VARCHAR, I tried manually adding it to my MySQL database but it overrides it with VARCHAR once again. When I edit the state type to ENUM it tells me:

> Unknown column type "enum" requested.

I use Symfony version 2.1

I followed and tried the following solutions:

- [How to enable ENUMs in Symfony 2 / Doctrine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312271/how-to-enable-enums-in-symfony-2-doctrine)
- [Adding ENUM to doctrine](http://forum.symfony-project.org/viewtopic.php?t=37406)
- [Mysql Enums](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/mysql-enums.html)
- [How do I set enum data type in doctrine 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12453448/how-do-i-set-enum-data-type-in-doctrine-2)
- [Doctrine 2: Resolving “unknown database type enum requested”](https://wildlyinaccurate.com/doctrine-2-resolving-unknown-database-type-enum-requested)