# Doctrine: Define Enum class as columDefinition for Entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a abstract Enum class

```
abstract class NotificationEnum
{
    const INFO = "info";
    const WARNING = "warning";
    const SUCCESS = "success";
    const ERROR = "error";
 [...]
 }
```

Now if i change the enum above, changes should also appear to the columDefinition for allowing these as inputs.

```
/**
 * @Column(type="string", type="string", columnDefinition="enum('info', 'warning', 'success', 'error')")
 * @Type("string")
 */
private $severity;
```

Is there a possibility to tell doctrine that the inputs can be of a given Type or should i do these things just on validation-level e.g just checking if the input is of a given Type?

thanks you advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I set enum data type in doctrine 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12453448/how-do-i-set-enum-data-type-in-doctrine-2)

Comment: Or this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18062382/right-way-to-define-and-work-with-enum-types-from-symfony2-and-doctrine2